# Android in-app purchase testing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I want test my in-app purchase implementation. But I can not configure it.
My app has a beta version in Developer Console, there are Google+ Community and Google Group in Beta Testers and my account added both to Community and Group. I added android:debuggable="true" in Manifest but Billing system still wants my money.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add emails of testers into `Google Play Console`. There is field in the settings tab, looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will ask about billing information.You can get your billing amount to your account within 14 days if you are a licensed tester in your play store development console.